# Terraform: How can I pass variables to user_data init script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-rds

I have been hanging around with this problem for some time now and I can't solve it.

I'm launching an EC2 instance that runs a bash script and installs a few things.
At the same time, I am also launching an RDS instance, but I need to be able to pass the value from the RDS endpoint to the EC2 instance to configure the connection.

I'm trying to do this using templatefile, like this

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instances" {
  count               = 1
  identifier          = "rds-prod-ddbb-${count.index}"
  cluster_identifier  = aws_rds_cluster.default.id
  instance_class      = "db.r5.large"
  engine              = "aurora"
  engine_version      = "5.6.mysql_aurora.1.22.5"
  publicly_accessible = "true"
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "default" {
  cluster_identifier      = "aws-rds-ddbb-cluster"
  availability_zones      = ["us-west-2b"]
  db_subnet_group_name    = "default-vpc-003d3ab296c"
  skip_final_snapshot     = "true"
  backup_retention_period = 30
  vpc_security_group_ids  = [aws_security_group.ddbb.id]
}

data "template_file" "RDSs" {
  template = file("init.sh")
  vars = {
    rds = aws_rds_cluster.default.endpoint
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_rds_cluster.default,
    aws_rds_cluster_instance.cluster_instances,
  ]
}

resource "aws_instance" "web_01" {
  ami                    = "ami-0477c9562acb09"
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id              = "subnet-0d0558d99ec3cd3"
  key_name               = "web-01"
  user_data_base64       = base64encode(data.template_file.RDSs.rendered)
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ddbb.id]
  ebs_block_device {
    device_name = "/dev/sda1"
    volume_type = "gp2"
    volume_size = 20
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "Web01"
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_rds_cluster.default,
    aws_rds_cluster_instance.cluster_instances,
  ]
}
```

And then, my `init.sh` is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "rds = $rds" > /var/tmp/rds
```

But I get nothing in `/var/tmp/rds`, so it looks like the variable `$rds` is empty.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Ps: I have outputs configured like this:

`outputs.tf`

```
output "rds_endpoint" {
  value = aws_rds_cluster.default.endpoint
}
```

And that is working fine, when the apply is complete, it shows me the value of rds endpoint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Disclaimer**: although this answer does address the syntax of the original question, there are far better ways to handle the underlaying use case. For this, see [@Perry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73090280/2123530).*

---

The variable is not a shell variable but a templated variable — so terraform will parse the file, regardless of its type and replace terraform variables in the said file.

Knowing this, `$rds` is not a terraform variable interpolation, [while `${rds}` is](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/strings.html#interpolation).

So, your bash script should rather be:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "rds = ${rds}" > /var/tmp/rds
```

Comment: Thaaaank you soooooooooo much!!! that is what I need, it's working perfect!
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Also it´s worthy to take a look at the cloud-watch logs and the rendered script(s) itself:
the script(s):
`/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/` (usually called part_xxx.sh)

the logs:
`/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

maybe this will help you debugging :)

Answer (score 8):

Since **Terraform 0.12** There is a more elegant way of passing variable to `user_data`

Instead of using the `data "template_file"` prefer using the new `templatefile` function in terraform

```
locals {
  WEB_SERVER_UNAME   = "your_username"
  WEB_SERVER_PASS    = "your_password"
}

resource "aws_instance" "web_01" {
  ....
  user_data_base64 = base64encode("${templatefile("${path.module}/user_data_script.sh", {
    WEB_SERVER_UNAME   = local.WEB_SERVER_UNAME
    WEB_SERVER_PASS    = local.WEB_SERVER_PASS
  })}")
  ....
}
```

By using `$rds` you are refering to variables inside your shell script or env vars, that is the reason why it is displaying nothing.

To use the template variables you need to interpolate in the following way `${variable}`

Refer this for further details :- https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/strings#string-templates